# Help regarding disappearing Facebook post

Tags: facebook

My Facebook posts disappear from profile after 30 days. I've checked and they are still in activity log and not hidden. They just did not appear on my timeline. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Check the settings to not archive the post after 30 days.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit dumb...where can I find the settings?